# Is it wise to define macro conditional statement within Precompilation unit?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, precompile, precompiled-headers

```
******* stdafx.h ********
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>

**************************

******* dummy.cpp ********
    #if defined (_MSC_VER)
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #endif
    /........ content ....../
**************************
```

when I compiled `dummy.cpp` ,following compiler error pops up with **Visual C++** compiler:

`error C2856: #pragma hdrstop cannot be inside an #if block`

In order to prevent above error I port `macro conditional` statement in to `stdafx.h` pre-coompilation as below:

```
    ******* stdafx.h ********
    #pragma once

    #if defined (_MSC_VER)
     #include "targetver.h"
     #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             
     // Windows Header Files:
     #include <windows.h>
    #endif 
    **************************
```

*Is this a good approach to avoid compilation error on above pre-compilation unit?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach won't work. Everything before precompiled header inclusion is ignored during compilation so `#if defined (_MSC_VER)` in `dummy.cpp` will be thrown away.

The better approach would be delete all the `#include "stdafx.h"` and include precompiled header through compilation option `Forced Include File`:

```
/FI"stdafx.h"
```

Comment: what did you mean by `Everything before precompiled header inclusion is ignored during compilation ` ? How about my second `stdafx,h` alternative? `macro` in `stdafx.h`

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga If `stdafx.h` is a precompiled header then all the lines above `#include "stdafx.h"` will be silently ignored during compilation. `stdafx.h` content is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you very much ... it works.. now I have to solve `C1853` `'.pch' precompiled header file is from a previous version of the compiler, or the precompiled header is C++ and you are using it from C (or vice versa)` :(

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga Well, I guess you should do full rebuild. Also just as this error text says, the same precompiled header should not be used for C and C++ translation units.

Comment: yeah , right now I won't use precompiled header with `c` files after all development I will change them to `Compile As C++` ..  rather than `Compile As C`I think it will avoid it.